# LEFT Join on a Correlated Subquery In BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables to left join in BigQuery. The data in the tables is as depicted below

```
T1
----------------------------
id      code       t1_date
101     xyz1       2010-10-23
102     xyz1       2023-10-01
103     abc2       2023-09-01          

T2
-------------------------------------------------
code         valid_date      SomeVal      
xyz1         2010-12-31        xxx
xyz1         2999-12-31        yyy 

Expected output
-------------------------------------------------
id      code       t1_date       SomeVal
101     xyz1       2010-10-23    xxx 
102     xyz1       2023-10-01    yyy
103     abc2       2023-09-01    null  <---SomeVal is null for this record as the code doesn't exists in T2
```

To get the expected result, I am trying to implement the logic as below but I am stuck on how to select the minimum row_number

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.SomeVal FROM T1 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT code,valid_date, ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY code ORDER BY 
           valid_date) as row_num from T2)
ON T1.code = T2.code
AND T1.t1_date <= T2.valid_date
```

Can someone help with the solution please.

Answer (score 0):

To find the best fit, the row number must be calculated after the join.

```sql
WITH
 T1 AS (
 SELECT 101 AS id, "xyz1" AS code, date "2010-10-23" t1_date
 UNION ALL SELECT 102, "xyz1", date "2023-10-01"
 UNION ALL SELECT 103, "abc2", date "2023-09-01" ),
 T2 AS (
 SELECT "xyz1" AS code, "2010-12-31" valid_date, "xxx" AS SomeVal
 UNION ALL SELECT "xyz1", date "2999-12-31", "yyy" )
SELECT
 T1.*,
 T2P.SomeVal,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T2P.code,id ORDER BY T2P.valid_date) AS row_num2
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT
 code,
 valid_date,
 SomeVal,
 #ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY code ORDER BY valid_date) AS row_num
 FROM
 T2) as T2P # the table needs to have an alias
ON
 T1.code = T2P.code
 AND T1.t1_date <= T2P.valid_date
 # where row_num=1
 Qualify row_num2=1
```

Please take in mind, that the join is not well performing when  there many entries for each code, because then a large table is generated only the be filtered by the closed entries. A better way is to union both tables and find the corresponding next date by a windows function call.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use QUALIFY

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.SomeVal FROM T1 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT code,valid_date, ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY code ORDER BY valid_date) as row_num from T2 QUALIFY row_num=1)
ON T1.code = T2.code
AND T1.t1_date <= T2.valid_date
```

More aboute QUALIFY clause: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#qualify_clause

Comment: Thank you for the response, but when we use QUALIFY, for id=102 the row_num=1 results in no data being fetched.